# Compress InputStream with GZIPOutputStream into ByteArray

Tags: java, inputstream, bytearrayoutputstream, gzipoutputstream, ioutils

I have a method that takes an InputStream as a parameter and I'm trying to compress the input stream using GZIPOutputStream and then return a compressed byte array. My code looks like this:

```
    public static byte[] compress(final InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    final int byteArrayOutputStreamSize = Math.max(32, inputStream.available());
    try(final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStreamSize);
    final GZIPOutputStream gzipOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream)) {
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, gzipOutputStream);
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

But somehow it doesn't seem to be working. I'm trying to perform unit testing on this with the following code:

```
    @Test
public void testCompress() throws Exception {
    final String uncompressedBytes = "some text here".getBytes();
    final InputStream inputStream = ByteSource.wrap(uncompressedBytes).openStream();
    final byte[] compressedBytes = CompressionHelper.compress(inputStream);
    Assert.assertNotNull(compressedBytes);
    final byte[] decompressedBytes = decompress(compressedBytes);
    Assert.assertEquals(uncompressedBytes, decompressedBytes);
}

public static byte[] decompress(byte[] contentBytes) throws Exception {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(contentBytes);
         InputStream inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(byteArrayInputStream)) {
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, out);
        return out.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this exception

> java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream

What I'm i doing wrong?

Comment: Define 'somehow when I compress it'.

Comment: I updated the description to be more clear

Comment: Sigh. You need to post your decompresson code, by which I do not mean posting the code that calls your decompression code.

Comment: Sorry I forgot, I updated again.

Comment: Evidently `IOUtils.copy()` doesn't close the output stream, so you have do that yourself. NB Your use of available() is both invalid and unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks closing the output stream fixed the issue. I'll remove the use of available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flushing and closing the output stream after copying the input stream into the output stream fixed the issue:

```
         IOUtils.copy(inputStream, gzipOutputStream);
         gzipOutputStream.flush();
         gzipOutputStream.close();
```

Comment: Although I beleive your answer is correct in its principle, I think you should highlight the mistake more precisely. You do flush and close the stream (because you use a try with resources). The issue is that you compute the return value before this closing happens. And flushing/closing explicitely is not really an option, because that will amount to closing the stream twice (once explicitely, the second time sith the try).

Comment: Thanks, I will update the answer to highlight the actual the issue. However, I don't think there is a problem with flushing and closing excplicility even if it is surrounded with a try-with-resources.

Comment: Flushing (or closing) a closed stream may or may not be supported. There is no contract on the API that states one way or another. I'll let you take your chances :-) (in practice it works with most basic streams I used, but your mileage may vary).